# Getting an earlier version of 4.x

Tags: font-awesome

I need a fresh download of FA version 4.0.3 as the CMS I use contained a damaged copy.  I tried using the latest (4.7.0 at this time), but CSS changes in the .fa selector cause placement issues.  I'd like to roll back to 4.0.3 to maintain compatibility until we can do a whole-site regression test for this type of bug once we upgrade.

Comment: You can grab whatever you like from the FA Github, no?

Comment: Maaaaaybe... just wasn't sure that was the best way to go about it.  I'll check, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complaining in the comments, I'll just drop this in here as a weak answer.

Either you download and stash it somewhere because you need to make changes (and then reference the CSS and other assets in the appropriate way as desribed on the [Get Started](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) page) or you use a reference to a CDN in a `link` to a stylesheet, in which case you can specify the version in the URL.

It sounds like you are doing the former, but you should be sure. Maybe you can just use the CDN link? At any rate, you can fetch [4.0.3 from the GitHub repo](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/v4.0.3)

Comment: Thanks; I discovered the "Releases" feature in GitHub and was able to grab it from there.  From there I found out (see my answer...)

Comment: I always forget about Releases.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a hold of v4.0.3 via the GitHub [Releases](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases?after=4.1.0) feature.

Having done that, I discovered that somebody had *modified* the CSS file in our CMS to add `margin-right: 5px` -- and it was one of the CMS's developers!  Naughty, naughty!

SO, the 'incompatibility' I saw was **not** between the official, unmodified 4.0.3 and 4.7.0 versions of FA.  Sorry about the false alarm!  And thanks for your help.  :)